# Dirichlet Process Clustering Prior

Tags: estimation, prior, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

I'm doing dirichlet process clustering where dirichlet priors are used as:
with CRP representation as:

- First customer will always choose first table.
- Second will choose already occupied table with
- probability `c/α + n - 1`
- and will choose unoccupied table with
- probability `α / α + n - 1` where
- `α` which is known as dirichlet prior and
- `c` is # of customers at occupied table
- `n` is total # of customers

Now if we use Collapsed Gibbs Sampling for initial assignments of group, `α` is also used as CRP probability in Collapased Gibbs Sampling. So the question is:

- *Should I myself assign a value to `α` or is there any technique to
  estimate `α`?*

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking at a [Chinese Restaurant process](https://www6.inra.fr/mia-paris/content/.../Tressou-ABARI29-06.pdf) ?  [link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vnair/ciar/frank_wood.ppt)

Comment: @EngrStudent yeah absolutely I want to Dirichlet Clustering using CRP as what I know, Dirichlet Clustering using Stick Breaking Construction or using CRP is almost same.

Comment: @EngrStudent These both links shared by you are not downloadable for me here, can you please share at _taufelaus@gmail.com_

Comment: @EngrStudent can you help me in estimating or inferring a value for `α` please?

Comment: You can put a prior on alpha and make a draw from its conditional posterior on each sweep.

Comment: @mef Can you please put something here in equation or variable form to make your suggestion more clearer?

Comment: @mef I have manually checked for different values of alpha > 0 where I found either all values going to a single cluster or all values going to separate cluster, can you spot out the flaw here?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "Dirichlet Process Clustering Prior" you mean you are using a "Dirichlet Process Mixture Model" to model your data. This would be the simplest model with DP.

As @mef pointed out you can put a vague gamma prior on $\alpha$, $\alpha \sim Gamma(a, b)$ and resample $\alpha$ as well as your table assignments. You can find the details in Escobar and West 95 paper, or in [this note by West.](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~mw/.downloads/DP.learnalpha.pdf)

Remember, these formulas are valid only if the conditional distribution of cluster labels follow a CRP. Otherwise they just give you an approximation.